# beforeclose callback of jquery dialog not executed on close

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, callback

I am trying to make fire a callback on dialog close, and I am unable to debug it from developer tools/firebug. The code defined after beforeclose label is never executed:

```
$(".dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 300,
    beforeclose: function(event, ui) 
    {
        // :input select all buttons, selects, textarea, checkbox
        $(':input').removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
    }
});
```

I get no errors from the console and I searched but no one seems to have the same problem.

I'll show more code if needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's case sensitive but in the API it's:

```
beforeClose
```

Source:
[API](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-beforeClose)

Comment: Seems not case-sensitive in Chrome/Firefox/Ie and Safari under windows7: http://jsfiddle.net/yMKPy/

Comment: Answer to my own comment:  it is case-sensitive in jquery 1.8+